# Python 3 installation, additional to existing Python 2 on Windows: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, installation, pythonpath

Sorry if this is a re-post. I have been searching for hours and there are a lot of similar problems, but they are not exactly the same as my issue. 
I have been working with Python27 on my 64bit Windows for a while now and I would like to install Python 3 in parallel.

I downloaded and executed the installation .exe of Python 3.5 for 64bit Windows. The installation worked without any errors and added C:/Python35 to the Windows PATH variable.
However, when I click on python.exe in the directory C:\Python35, instead of launching a python 3.5 shell as it's supposed to do, it pops up a Window saying

> Python has stopped working

Also there is a command shell saying:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system
>   codec   File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings__init__.py", line 123
>       raise CodecRegistryError,\
>                               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Current thread 0x00001ce0 (most recent call first):

So appearently Python 3.5 is using the Lib directory of Python 2.7. This is probably related to the PYTHONPATH variable that is set to

> C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk

When I change the PYHTONPATH variable to

> C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python35\Lib\lib-tk

Python 3.5 works, but Python 2.7 throws the error above.

Is there any way to permanently define that the command "python3" uses one `PYTHONPATH` and the command `"python2"` uses another `PYTHONPATH`?

Copying python.exe and renaming it to python3.exe didn't help. Neither did uninstalling and installing Python 3.5 again.

I have a lot of old jupyter notebooks that are written in Python 2.7 and it would be great if I could continue to use them by choosing different kernels (see [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)).